# cannot override ButtonCell onBrowserEvent in header cell

Tags: button, gwt, datagrid, gwt-celltable

Please help, I spent hours trying to passe an Event on my ButtonCell in a footer, but nothing happens it rather takes the Event of the colomn.

I created my header cell like this

```
    Header<String> buttFooterPilote = new Header<String>(new ButtonCell()) {

    @Override
    public String getValue() {
    return I18nSteering.getButtons().unlockPRSelected();

    }



};buttFooterPilote.setUpdater(new ValueUpdater<String>() {

    @Override
    public void update(String value) {

    List<Integer> selectedPRIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (PRGui pr : selectionModel.getSelectedSet()) {
        if (pr.isLocked()) {
        selectedPRIds.add(pr.getId());
        }
    }
    PrGuiDataTable.this.fireEvent(new UnlockPilotPointEvent(selectedPRIds));


    }
});

super.addColumn(pilotModeColumn, addHeaderPiloteColomn, buttFooterPilote);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved, my code works perfectly the setUpdater overrides the click event. The thing was that my UnlockPilotPointEvent was not triggered because selectedPRIds was null that's all